# Сравнение изображения на попадание в область

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.778042,-122.419136),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        panControl: true
    });

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
        },
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rect) {

        var bounds = rect.getBounds();

        console.log(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() + ', ' + bounds.getNorthEast().lng());
        console.log(bounds.getSouthWest().lat() + ', ' + bounds.getSouthWest().lng());

    });

});
```

Тут я получаю координаты двух точек нарисованного на карте прямоугольника. У этих двух точек я вывожу широту и долготу. В базе хранятся изображения с координатами. Мне нужно сравнить каждое из них на попадание в область прямоугольника. Как это лучше и проще сделать? Есть мысль использовать метод intersects. То есть что-то типа этого:

допустим у нас уже имеется массив изображений images и у каждого из них есть свойство bounds.

```
for(var i = 0; i < images; i++){
  if(bounds.intersects(images[i].bounds)){
    console.log('match');
  }
}
```

Я еще не проверял данный код, но хочется узнать, в правильном ли направлении я иду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В правильном, именно для этого метод intersects и предназначен, только у вас чего то не хватает в условии цикла.

```
for (var i = 0, img; (img = images[i]) !== undefined; i++) {
    if(bounds.intersects(img.bounds)) {
        console.log('true');
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, я забыл добавить length в цикле. А Ваш цикл я что-то не очень понимаю.

Comment: В примерах по гугл картам часто можно встретить такой формат записи. Иногда позволяет экономить одну строчку кода. Если внутри цикла у вас идет частое обращение к текущему элементу цикла arr[i], то скорее всего вы, внутри цикла, определитет переменную elem = arr[i]. В примере, который я вам написал, определение этой самой переменной происходит в самом цикле.

Comment: Проще говоря это кэширование значения в переменную. Интересный подход.